# PayPal amount_x in IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

What's variable name for **amount_x** (item price) that is submited back from PayPals IPN?
Im searching everywhere but cant find the name of this item price variable in IPN?!

I can get it like:

```
$_POST['mc_gross_'.$i] / $_POST['quantity'.$i]
```

But I'm not sure because of rounding, etc.

Answer (score -1):

$_POST['mc_gross'] is the total amount for the payment. Are you wanting individual item prices?

Comment: mc_gross is total, but I need price for single and only for one item, that I already provided during checkout.

Comment: @Bobo Here is the full documentation: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf

Comment: @Bobo On page 424 of https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf lists individual item variables.